# orientation change listener in expo react native not firing?

Tags: react-native, expo

i want to detect the current orientation of device in expo react native, this is my code that doesn't work:

```
import {
 Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';**
const App = () => {
...
useEffect(() => {
    const isPortrait = () => {
      const dimension = Dimensions.get('screen');
      return dimension.height >= dimension.width;
    };
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => {
      const orientation = isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';
      console.log('Dimensions orientation', orientation);
    });
    ScreenOrientation.addOrientationChangeListener((e) => {
      console.log('e ', e);
    });
  }, []);
```

how ever when i rotate the device there is no logs so it's not firing?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```js
const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(
  ScreenOrientation.Orientation.PORTRAIT_UP
);

useEffect(() => {
  // set initial orientation
  ScreenOrientation.getOrientationAsync().then((info) => {
    setOrientation(info.orientation);
  });

  // subscribe to future changes
  const subscription = ScreenOrientation.addOrientationChangeListener((evt) => {
    setOrientation(evt.orientationInfo.orientation);
  });

  // return a clean up function to unsubscribe from notifications
  return () => {
    ScreenOrientation.removeOrientationChangeListener(subscription);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

This is the line that doesn't do anything. Broken, bugged, POS? All of the above?

```
ScreenOrientation.addOrientationChangeListener((e) => {
 console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set your `orientation` field as `default` in your `app.json / app.config.js`. The app is locked to the specified orientation if this field is set to another value.

Related doc is here:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v46.0.0/config/app/#orientation

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong package.

From the `expo-screen-orientation` [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/):

> Screen Orientation is defined as the orientation in which graphics are painted on the device. ... For physical device orientation, see the orientation section of [Device Motion](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/devicemotion/).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. The listener function was never firing.

Adding `expo-sensors` to my project seems to have fixed the callback for me. I think `expo-screen-orientation` might depend on `expo-sensors`

Steps for adding:

1. `npx expo install expo-sensors`
2. Rebuild your expo development client. (For me that command is `eas build --profile simulator`, but that will depend on your eas config)

After that, the listener callback function started firing.

Here's a code snippet of where I add the listener:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ScreenOrientation.addOrientationChangeListener((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me full doc here (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#screenorientationgetorientationasync)

`npm i expo-screen-orientation`

add plugins and require full screen to `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "requireFullScreen": true
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-screen-orientation",
        {
          "initialOrientation": "DEFAULT"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

clean build folder and rebuild
`cd ios && pod deintegrate && pod setup && pod install`

you are going to prob want to add a enum to tell which screen orientation it is in so this is optional

```
export enum ScreenOrientationEnum {
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    PORTRAIT_UP = 1,
    PORTRAIT_DOWN = 2,
    LANDSCAPE_LEFT = 3,
    LANDSCAPE_RIGHT = 4
}
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `app.json` file and see if you have this line in there

```
"orientation": "portrait"
```

It prevents the device from changing its orientation, as it is being fixed to portrait only. Getting rid of it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using expo bare workflow (you have access to the native code), update your `AndroidManifest.xml` to use `fullSensor`:

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
  android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" <- this line
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Expo and just want your app to rotate when you rotate your phone, you need to add one line to the app mount

```
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';

...

useEffect(() => {
    ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.DEFAULT);
}, []);
```

Now when you rotate your phone, it will either ask you to rotate the app with an arrows icon or if you have auto-rotation enabled it will rotate your app right away.

Don't forget to reload your app in Expo Go

And don't forget to follow official Expo ScreenOrientation documentation, it's important that you `app.json` right